# How to validate user's input when a form is submitted using the "Job, Event, Listener design pattern"?

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, event-handling

I am trying to use Job, Event, Listener design pattern for an application that I am working on.

I am new to Laravel and to this design pattern, but I think it is a good fit for what I need.

**This is a quick overview of that I am working on:**

I have 3 different pages. Each page has a form. When a user finish the first form, I need to direct them to the second form, then to the third once the second is completed. Once the third form is completed, I want to route the user to a different page "list of records."

**Here is what I have done so far** "I hope I am somewhat on the right track"

In my controller, I have two methods. First method "Show()", displays the correct form based on the interview stage "stage1, stage2, stage 3." The second method "store()". This method will store the form data into a database.

When the show() route is hit, I dispatch StartInterview and DisplayQuestions jobs.

After the interview is started then I fire InterviewWasStarted event. Then when the questions displayed "new form" then I fire QuestionsWasDisplayed Event.

Both events have listeners that currently do nothing "may be I will utilize later."

Then, when a user hit "submit" button, the "store()" method will be executed.

In the "store" route, I dispatch SaveAnswers and SaveInterview Job. The SaveAnswers Job will take the form values and submit them into a database. Then the SaveInterview will update the interview table stating that the user is currently on form #2 or form #3.

**Guidance please**

I have few questions that I am not sure what is the best "right way" to do. How would I validate the form? Would I create a job that validates the form? If so would I dispatch it from the store() method in the controller or would I dispatch it from the SaveAnswers Job? "Does it make since to dispatch a job from with in another job?" I always will need to validate before I save so both jobs should be coupled some how as the SaveAnswer should abort if the validation fails.

How do I direct the user to a new page once the third page have been completed? Does it make since to route a user from inside of a listener "sounds like a bad idea to me"? Would I redirect the use from WhenInterviewCompleted listener. would I create flash data from inside the listener and check for flash data in the controller?

I think my problem is that I am still thinking in procedural code term not from "Tell, don't ask" mentality.

I appreciate a well explained answer to help me code in the right path